# Default case compilation when switching over all items of an enum class

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Why does the following switch even compiles the default case since it covers all items of the enum class? 
I would have thought that this was the reason for having strong `enum class` in the first place.

As to why I would like to have a default even though I know that I cover all cases : This safe-guards me against my future careless-ness (and that of other coworkers)

```
enum class E {
    a,
    b
};

int main()
{
    E c = E::b;
    switch (c) {
        case E::a:
        case E::b:
            std::cout << "pass" << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            static_assert(false, "This explodes!");
    }    
}
```

[Proof](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=da4d489de0341eeebc838ef39edafb54-cf309a81c3a64a9a75c8145c94b8ae21)

Comment: A `static_assert` checks its condition and if it's non-dependent and evaluates to false, it fires as soon as it's parsed.

Comment: Note that some compilers (GCC) can be configured to emit a warning and/or error if you have a switch statement with no default clause that does not specify a clause for every value in the enum.  This would protect against future developers adding values to 'E' without adding a corresponding 'case' clause.  Granted it does not cover the cases where 'c' has a value that isn't one of the enumerations in 'E'.

Comment: The compiler may be optimising out the switch altogether since the input is given in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the compile can't know if someone casted an illegal value to the enum type. Consider:

```
E c = static_cast<E>( 42 );
```

The cast will compile without a warning (or even an error) as you are explicitly telling the compiler "I know what I'm doing, don't check the value". In practice, this sadly happens more often than you think. :(

Also, all code needs to be valid, even if it is later removed as unreachable. A `static_assert(false,...)` will fire at compile-time, independent of what would happen at run-time.

Comment: That's not an illegal value. This kind of thing is explicitly allowed for enums, and is often quite useful.

Comment: @PeteBecker: You mean if the enum models flags which can be combined or something like that? In that case, yes, true, it's technically allowed. I was using *illegal* to refer to the OPs use case where he (obviously?) wanted only the listed values `a` and `b` to be valid, so illegal means the intended semantic level, not the technical one.

Answer (score 0):

Enums are not restricted to the values that you name. They are restricted to values that fit in the underlying type, which is an integral type large enough to hold all the values. For example:

```
enum flags {
    first = 0x01,
    second = 0x02,
    third = 0x04,
    fourth = 0x08
};

flags operator | (flags f0, flags f1) {
    return flags((int)f0 | (int)f1);
}

flags f = first | second; // okay; f holds 0x03
```

Comment: note that question subject is C++11 `enum class`; please fix your code

Comment: For anyone wondering, adding the `class` and `flags::` scopes still shows that C++ is equally happy to perform bitwise flag-style arithmetic between the members and assign the result to another instance of the `enum class`, in a this 'stricter' enumeration, as it would be with an old plain one.